# C++ Random String return unexpected results

Tags: c++, c, arrays, char

I am trying to use a function to generate a `char[]` :

```
char* randString(){
    const int len = 5;
    char s[len] = {0};

    static const char alphanum[] =
        "0123456789"
        "!@#$%^&*"
        "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
        "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    int stringLength = sizeof(alphanum) - 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        s[i] = alphanum[rand() % stringLength];
    }

    return s;
}
```

the result is random and expected at `return s`

```
+       s   0x002df990 "XnQWp...    char[5]
```

however, when i look at the value here:

```
char* rand = randString();
```

it contains strange values:

```
+       rand    0x002df990 "XnQWpÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ\x5"    char *
```

did I do something wrong in the return?

Comment: It's because you're returning a local pointer.

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish what do you mean? 
@Mat how is `char s[len] = {0}` out of bounds? I thought that was how you are supposed to init things

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can a local variable's memory be accessed outside its scope?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope)

Comment: @Mat, the second line is a variable definition, not an assignment

Comment: @Epicblood, return strdup(s) instead (and remember to free(s) in the caller when no longer needed)

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish so you mean i should pass in a `char*` and modify that?

Comment: @Epicblood That would probably be the best way to do it.

Comment: As a side note, this would be more accurately tagged C than C++.

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish now the last val in the `char[]` is always `-52 'Ì'`

Comment: @Epicblood yes, pass a buffer *and* its length (a `size_t` ideally) as input params and let the function sort it out, including setting a terminating null (which you didn't forget, *right* ?).

Comment: @WhozCraig i may have forgotten xD thanks

Comment: it's c++, take a look at the alternative and safer ways: [rand() considered harmful](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're declaring `char s[]` as a local variable. Local variables are destroyed when the function returns so returning a pointer to that variable returns a pointer pointing to junk data.

Fix this by allocating `s` dynamically:

`char* s = new char[len];`

Or you could pass a `char*` as a parameter and write your character to that array.

Just remember to add the terminating null character before returning.

Comment: and remember to delete[] it in the end, don't forget